# MongoDB: Find documents that have a matching field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is a bit trickier than one might first think. Or maybe I am just overthinking the problem.

#### Here is how I retrieve (two) random documents from MongoDB:

```
Character
  .find({ random: { $near: [Math.random(), 0] } })
  .where('voted', false)
  .limit(2)
  .exec(function(err, characters) {
    res.send({ characters: characters });
  }
});
```

What I would like to add is - **finding by gender**. Each document already has a gender field with value set to either *female* or *male*. What I need in other words: **Give me two random documents that have a matching gender field.**

***Example***:
2 random females, 2 random males, 2 random males, 2 random females, etc...

*For more information on how to retrieve a random document from MongoDB: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your collection is large enough I think you can simply add random `gender` field to the query

```
var choices = {0: 'female', 1: 'male'}

.find({
    gender: choices[Math.round(Math.random())],
    random: { $near: [Math.random(), 0] }
})
```

but it won't solve the problem that your current results aren't really random. If you use `limit(1)` everything works like supposed, but when the limit is set to 2 things aren’t so simple. Let's say you have very simple collection like this:

```
> db.foo.find({}, {_id: 0}
{ "random" : [  1,  0 ] }
{ "random" : [  2,  0 ] }
{ "random" : [  3,  0 ] }
{ "random" : [  4,  0 ] }
{ "random" : [  5,  0 ] }
```

and perform query `random: { $near: [Math.random() * 4 + 1, 0] } })` with `limit(2)`. Every time the nearest document is `{ "random" : [  3,  0 ] }` as a second you'll get `{ "random" : [  2,  0 ] }` or `{ "random" : [  4,  0 ] }`.

Probably the best solution would to perform n separate queries and retrieving single random document each time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I noticed this problem but was hoping I wouldn't have to make 2 queries. As for the gender, the whole point is not to specify the gender. If one document is female, then other document must also be female. The next two documents could be male or female.

Comment: If you don't mind that I think that random choice of gender should be more than enough. I've updated the answer.